# UI not updating while using Knockout Observable Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I am new to knockout. I am trying to use observable arrays to track the changes from UI. The UI is loading with the initial data which is stored in the array. And i am trying to add new object into the array dynamically from another screen.

Now i am able to add new object into the array. But UI is not getting reflected with new changes in the array. Below is my html and javascript code.

Am i missing something.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.css " type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prodconfig.css " type="text/css" />    
    <script src="jquery.mobile.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cordys.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="knockout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="prodconfig.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="productsPage" class="dataContainer">
        <div id="productDetails">
            <div data-role="content" id="productTable">
                <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th data-priority="6">Product Name</th>
                          <th data-priority="1">Description</th>
                          <th data-priority="2">Parent?</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="pBody"  data-bind="foreach: products">
                        <tr class="success">
                          <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
                          <td><span data-bind="text: desc"></span></td>
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="prodButtons">
            <button id="addProdProduct">Add Product</button>
            <button id="addProdChar">Add Characteristics</button>
            <button id="prodButton">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="addProductPage" data-role="page" >
        <span><h3>Product Name</h3></span><input type="text" id="prodNameId"></input>
        <span><h3>Product Desc</h3></span><input type="text" id="prodDescId"></input>
        <span><h3>Is Parent</h3></span><input type="text" id="prodIsParentId"></input>
        <button id="addProdButton">OK</button>
    <div>
</body>
```

```
var configArray = new Array();
var products = [];
var services = new Array();
var chars = [];
var prd;



for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    var product = new Object();
    product["name"] = "prod"+i+"Name";
    product["desc"] = "prod"+i+"Desc";
    product["isParent"] = "prme";

    for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
            var charr = new Object();
            charr["name"] = "prod"+i+"char"+j;
            charr["val"] = "prod"+i+"char"+j+"val";
            chars[j] = charr;
    }
    product["chars"] = chars;
    products[i] = product;

}

var ProductViewModel =  function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
    this.addItem = function() {
        if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
            this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); 
            this.itemToAdd(""); 
        }
    }.bind(this);  
};

$(function(){
    $('#addProdProduct').click(function() {
        window.location.href = "#addProductPage";
    });
    $('#addProdButton').click(function() {
        addProduct();
    });
    prd = new ProductViewModel(products);
    ko.applyBindings(prd);

});

function addProduct(){
    var product = new Object();
    product["name"] = $('#prodNameId').val();
    product["desc"] = $('#prodDescId').val();
    product["isParent"] = $('#prodIsParentId').val();
    prd.itemToAdd(product);
    prd.addItem();
    window.location.href = '#';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding to the `products` variable instead of to the `items` field on your viewmodel.

Change your binding to:

```
<tbody id="pBody"  data-bind="foreach: items">
```

Comment: Aah...i missed that part as it was working for the initial content.

Comment: that's because you in initial for loop you are assigning data to  `products ` which is plane variable of array type (non-observable) .

Answer (score 0):

The code below shown a sample procedure for inserting data using knockoutjs MVVM pattern. Here i using bootstrap Modal Popup for inserting Data.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-bind="click:add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Data
</button>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template:{name:'item-view-template',foreach:products}"></tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="item-view-template">
<tr>
    <td class="text-left" data-bind="text:ProductName"></td>
    <br />
/tr>
</script>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Data</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-bind="template:{name:'item-create-template',data:selectedData}">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <script type="text/html" id="item-create-template">
   <form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:ProductName" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:$parent.save">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = new ProductViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    vm.init();
  </script>
```

View Model Js File

```
function ProductViewModel() {
var self = {};
self.data = ko.observableArray();
self.products = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedData = ko.observable(Product({}));

self.init = function () {
    $.get('/MyController/GetAll', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            self.products.push(Product(value));
        });
    });
};
self.add = function () {
    self.selectedData(Product({}));
};
self.save = function() {
    if (self.selectedData()) {
        var jsonData = ko.toJS(self.selectedData);
        $.post('/MyController/Create', jsonData, function(data) {
            if (data.Status == true) {
                $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
                bootbox.alert("Product created successfully", function() {
                    self.Products.removeAll();
                    $.get('/MyController/GetAll', function (result) {
                        $.each(result.Products, function (key, value) {
                            self.Products.push(Product(value));
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else {
                bootbox.alert("Duplicate values not allowed..!!");
            }
        });
    } else {
       bootbox.alert("Error!!");
    }
};
return self;
}
```

And the Model

```
function Product(product) {
var self = {};
self.Id = ko.observable(product.Id || '');
self.ProductName = ko.protectedObservable(product.Name || '');
return self;
}
```

I think this will help you